# Why is my instanstiation not spawning an object after an enemy Game Object is destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here][1]Originally, this was a null reference exception, which is a problem that occur when a variable is used/referenced but hasn't been initialized. I used an if statement that checks if an instance is NOT null it would instantiate. The Null reference exception problem is gone but it still wouldn't instantiate.

ScraptScript.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScrapScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

public GameObject[] ScrapSprite;

EnemyScript Es;


void Start () 
{
    Es = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<EnemyScript> ();

    foreach(GameObject SSprite in ScrapSprite)
    {
        print (SSprite);
    }


}


void Update () 
{

}

public void SpawnScraps()
{
    if(Es != null   )
    {
        Instantiate (ScrapSprite[0], Es.transform.position, Es.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

}

EnemyDestroyed.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyDestroyed : MonoBehaviour {

BulletScript.BulletType theBulletType = 0;


ScrapScript SS;

void Start () 
{
    SS = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ScrapScript> ();
}

void Update () 
{

}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if(collider.tag == "PlayerBullet" && theBulletType == BulletScript.BulletType.PlayerBullet)
    {
        print ("ship destroyed");
        Destroy(collider.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        SS.SpawnScraps ();  
    }

    if(collider.tag == "L.Collider Det")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
```

}

EnemyScript.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int enemyHP;
public float enemySpeed;

public GameObject enemyBullet;

internal int enemyBulletCount = 0;
public int maxAllowableBulletCount;

public Transform enemyBulletSpawn;

public EnemyType ET;

public enum EnemyType
{
    Grunt,
    Boss,
}

void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine (MyShootCoroutine ());
}

void Start () 
{

}


void Update () 
{
    if (ET == EnemyType.Grunt) 
    {
        transform.Translate (-enemySpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);

    }
}

IEnumerator MyShootCoroutine()
{


    for(enemyBulletCount = 0; enemyBulletCount <= maxAllowableBulletCount; enemyBulletCount++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.5f);
        Instantiate (enemyBullet, enemyBulletSpawn.position, enemyBulletSpawn.rotation);
    }   

}
```

}

Expectation: What I expected of my code is to spawn a pickup currency called "Scraps" that the player will get upon contact when the enemy is destroyed. It spawns exactly where the enemy is destroyed through the player's bullets.

Screenshot link
[enter image description here][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iq11.png

Comment: You are destroying the gameobject before making the call to spawn the scraps `SS.SpawnScraps();`. Just rearrange those lines.

Comment: That shouldnt be the case. How would my gameobject be destroyed if i didnt set that specific object to be destroyed?

Comment: `Destroy(gameObject);` this line is destroying the gameobject that this script is attached to.

Comment: Its attached to an enemy so it wouldnt be possible for the SpawnScrap Function to be destroyed.

Comment: it's destroying your EnemyScript function, which means it never reaches the line `SS.SpawnScraps();` right below

Comment: Ok then what would you want me to rearrange in those code to make it spawn?

Comment: try putting `SS.SpawnScraps();` before `Destroy(collider.gameObject);`

Comment: Ok I placed it before the Destroy(collider.gameObject); but it still doesnt spawn the scrap object when the enemy object is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Given that you had a null reference exception in SpawnScraps method on the Es object the only issue is that when your method is called the Es object has been destroyed.

Given that you kill your ennemy instance before trying to call a method on him, you get a null reference exception :

```
Destroy(collider.gameObject);
Destroy(gameObject);
SS.SpawnScraps ();
```

Just make call the SpawnScraps method before destroying the ennemy GameObject :

```
SS.SpawnScraps ();
Destroy(collider.gameObject);
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: Ok I placed it before the Destroy(collider.gameObject); but it still doesnt spawn the scrap object when the enemy object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Within your scrap script, your Es is likely still null. This may because your script only finds the Enemyscript during Start().
You can remove this check and simplify things by passing the transform of the enemy into your SpawnScraps function.

within Enemydestroyed change your line to:

```
SS.SpawnScraps (transform);
```

within Scraptscript change existing function to:

```
public void SpawnScraps(Transform enemy)
{
    Instantiate (ScrapSprite[0], enemy.position, enemy.rotation);
}
```

Comment: where exactly and what line do u want me to put SS.SpawnScraps (transform) in Scrap Script and what about the void OnTriggerEnter function in the EnemyDestroyed class?

Comment: I tried it your suggestion, though im confused that why does SS.PawnScraps (transform) is in Enemyscript. However, it calls an null reference exception since the if statement that checks if its NOT null is removed as it is implied from your answer.

Comment: it should be in enemydestroyed, I misread and edited my answer

Comment: problem still persists as it calls an null reference exception since the if statement that checks if its NOT null is removed as it is implied from your answer.( if only i can screenshot it in the comments section).

Comment: Which part is it saying is null? can you paste that portion of the error.

Comment: Let's discuss [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163959/question-discussion)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant since i need 20 reputation points to chat
proof: https://imgur.com/a/1iQiN

Comment: Womp. Okay I am assuming your Enemydestroyed.cs is attached to the enemy. If you remove the Destroy(gameobject), does it still give you the null reference?

Comment: yup it still does.

Comment: Ill be inactive for the night since its 11:45pm here so ill come and check back on the comments section tom if you recently reply to me.

Comment: still scratching my head. I am not seeing how it's possible that the enemy transform is a null reference if the object is never destroyed.

Comment: Ok im back, would u like me to send you my code instead so u can see what went wrong with my code?